# Should I use change or input event to save data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, sql-update, client-side

I'm still learning the best way to do things through jQuery and Javascript.  I've got several input text boxes that I want to instantaneously update a record with when a change is made.

Handling a similar event from a Winforms perspective in the past, I would have handled this in the handler for a text change or got / lost focus event.  I understand that "input" and "change" are the rough equivalents of these for input elements.

I want to ensure that 100% of the time that a change is made when the text is changed.  My concern with using the "input" event is the possible overhead involved, while my concern with the "change" event is something out of the event's scope to handle (such as a browser closing, session expiration, etc.) would occur and prevent the update.

I'd prefer to use "input", but the thought of having a database hit every time someone types or deletes a character worries me.  "Change" would be ok if I had a way to prevent the scenario I mentioned above.

The bottom-line is this:  "Input" if overhead isn't a concern; "Change" if there is a way (which I'm not currently aware of) to ensure everything gets saved, possibly by handling another event as well.

What should I do?  Thanks!

Comment: Using `input` and throttling your AJAX calls (i.e. only send one after a delay of .5-1 seconds) would likely be the best bet. There's a jQuery plugin that handles that for you but I can't recall its name.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the input event isn't supported in all browsers, you'll have to provide a fallback for browsers that don't support it. (such as keydown with a check to ensure the event doesn't happen twice in browsers that support both)

Comment: There are plugins/libraries that normalize the `input` event...at least attempt to, to make it cross-browser compatible. Just have some `timeout`/`interval` run on the page (like every 5 seconds) that checks to see if the input has changed since the last time an AJAX request was sent. If it has, then send the request, otherwise ignore the event. 5 seconds seems often enough. I know you want it to be very accurate, but anything less than like 15 should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I went with the timeout / interval approach b/c of the problematic nature of the input event in some browsers, and it works great.  Let's just hope that all of these browsers get on the same page sometime soon (ha).